# How to manage multiple parallel threads in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

#### Scenario:

I am using node.js for writing a heavy application that listens to the tweets using streaming API, and for every tweet - it calls 3-4 REST APIs, then listens to a web socket for about 5-10 minutes and again calls 2 more REST apis.

#### Current Approach:

Though I have prepared functions for every task but I am not using callbacks. From tweet function F, I call another function F1 then from inside of F1 I call F2 and so on...

#### Problem:

It makes the code super messy and **MAJORLY**- the problem is that the concurrent requests are overlapping and sharing data among each other. For eg- while listening to a web socket I pass endpoint and auth info -

```
listenXYZ(endpoint, auth)
```

But it seems when two threads hit this function at same time then same endpoint is passed in those 2 sometimes.

- Why does this happen?
- How can I accomplish multi-threading with nice and organized data flow with controlled memory management?
- Can I use workers?
- Multi threading?

Comment: It's unlikely we can understand your problem without seeing at least some of the relevant code.  And, some of what you say is confusing.  Like how you can "not use callbacks" in node.js when  you're using IO.  My wild guess is that you should create an object that represents a current activity and store all state for that activity in that object and then each activity has its own object and then they won't confuse data stored globally.

Comment: you should not use the word "thread" because it's not what you mean it is. look into async module https://github.com/caolan/async this is how the cool kids handle none-blocking stuff in node

Comment: I would suggest a `message queue`. And I'd also go even further and suggest that you switch to `python` for this task. [`Celery` handles this quite gracefully](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time)

Comment: I would like to see your code. My guess is that you're doing this terribly wrong. A good way of handling async programming in `javascript` is [`Promises`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). Note that `node` is single threaded.

Comment: I can think of several ways I might solve this, but without more specific details on the problem it's not really possible to provide decent answers. Since everything you're describing is I/O, you do NOT need multithreading, this is bog-standard async I/O stuff. I'd probably use Promises, I can envision a pretty straightforward solution. But if you don't know them it's not easy to explain.